# Python - How can I access variables of an above class within a class within a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm not sure if this is possible within the language or not, but imagine this:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.variable_to_access = "I want this"
        self.object_list = []
        for i in range(number): self.object_list.append(Object_In_List(i))

class Object_In_List(object):
    def __init__(self): pass

    def my_method(self):
        # How can I access variable_to_access
```

I have over simplified this but I was thinking `Object_In_List` could inherit `Parent` but `Parent` will contain many other items and I am concerned about memory usage.

I want to avoid passing the `variable_to_access` itself constantly. Is this actually possible to access `variable_to_access` within `my_method()`?

Thanks

Comment: You need to pass the value to the object, or, make it global.

Comment: "I am concerned about memory usage". Don't do premature optimization. Class and instance dicts can [share keys](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0412/), this can reduce significantly the amount of memory required. Besides, if memory was *really* a problem you'd have to avoid using classes altogether and use plain `tuple`s instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slightly more complicated example which behaves like Java inner classes

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.variable_to_access = "I want this"
        self.object_list = [] for i in range(number): 
            # Pass in a reference to the parent class when constructing our "inner class"
            self.object_list.append(Object_In_List(self, i))

class Object_In_List(object):
    # We need a reference to our parent class
    def __init__(self, parent, i):
        self.parent = parent

    # ... So we can forward attribute lookups on to the parent
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.parent, name)

    # Now we can treat members of the parent class as if they were our own members (just like Java inner classes)
    def my_method(self):
        # You probably want to do something other than print here
        print(self.variable_to_access)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.variable_to_access = "I want this"
        self.object_list = []
        for i in range(number):
            self.object_list.append(Object_In_List(self.variable_to_access, i))

class Object_In_List(object):
    def __init__(self, parent_var, i):
        self.pv = parent_var

    def my_method(self):
        # How can I access variable_to_access
        # self.pv is what you want
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now it seems the only place that any `Object_In_List` objects exists are within the `Parent` attribute `self.object_list`. If that is the case then you are in the `Parent` class when accessing the `Object_In_List` already, so you don't even need `my_method` in `Object_In_List`. If these objects exist outside of that list then you would have to pass the `Parent` object or variable anyway, as shown in the other answers.

If you want to be creative you could play with class attributes of `Parent`. This would not be as "variable" though, unless your class attribute was a dictionary, but then there is the memory thing.